# How can i access the photo from gallery using Photo framework in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, photo-gallery

I am new on Photo framework i don't know how to use it. I have use many link but i have confused how to display image in imageview.

I want to get the all photo from gallery using photo framework i am trying

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *recentsDataSource;
PHFetchResult *assetCollection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum | PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:nil];
    for (PHAssetCollection *sub in assetCollection)
    {
        PHFetchResult *assetsInCollection = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:sub options:nil];

        for (PHAsset *asset in assetsInCollection)
        {
            [self.recentsDataSource addObject:asset];
        }
    }

    if (self.recentsDataSource.count > 0)
    {
        NSArray *array = [self.recentsDataSource sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]]];
        NSLog(@"Photo Array : %@",array);
        self.recentsDataSource = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc]initWithArray:array];
    }
```

i have get this type of array.

> Photo Array : (
>       " 5A2ABD38-D724-42B1-939A-F557D5CCE9FC/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   sourceType=1, (328x328), creationDate=2015-10-14 06:06:22 +0000,
>   location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0 ",
>       " 5391482F-9887-4518-9976-D5D544CDF8CA/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   sourceType=1, (450x800), creationDate=2015-10-12 09:27:41 +0000,
>   location=0, hidden=0, favorite=1 ",
>       " 3B921984-6E79-4E4D-B70D-C7FFB0AC1C63/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   sourceType=1, (3000x2002), creationDate=2012-08-08 09:25:30 +0000,
>   location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 ",
>       " D64D501E-F85D-4EE8-9C79-414272621A80/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   sourceType=1, (1668x2500), creationDate=2012-08-08 08:59:49 +0000,
>   location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 ",
>       " 46A57980-9C55-42A8-9792-6BD98B25F01D/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   sourceType=1, (3000x2002), creationDate=2012-08-08 06:22:11 +0000,
>   location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 ",
>       " 1E040EE9-99A9-4325-AB1F-CBF4E45111DA/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   sourceType=1, (4288x2848), creationDate=2011-03-12 10:47:25 +0000,
>   location=1, hidden=0, favorite=1 ",
>       " BF3A71CD-3065-43C0-A933-DD89BBE8C778/L0/001 mediaType=1/0,
>   sourceType=1, (4288x2848), creationDate=2009-10-09 08:39:20 +0000,
>   location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0 " )

How to display image on imageview.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add this in .h/.m file

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
```

Global variable :

```
@property(nonatomic , strong) PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResults;
@property(nonatomic , strong) PHCachingImageManager *imageManager;
```

viewDidLoad code :

```
// Fetch all assets, sorted by date created.
    PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
    _assetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];

    _imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
```

numberOfItemsInSection method :

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_assetsFetchResults count];
}
```

UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: code :

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell  = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
PHAsset *asset = _assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];

        [_imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:imageView.frame.size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info)
         {
             imageView.image = result;
         }];
```

[EDITED]

Accessing the image:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PHAsset *asset = _assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];

   [_imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info)
         {
             // result is the actual image object.
         }];
}
```

Comment: it will display same result as well I want to get the Date of Image. :)

Comment: NSDate *creationDate; NSDate *modificationDate; These are two properties of PHAsset . You can directly get it from asset object.  e.g. : asset.creationDate or asset.modificationDate.

Comment: you have to make changes in the viewDidLoad method and get the creationDate for each object. Make a dictionary with date as key and object as NSArray which contains all the PHAsset created on that date.

Comment: I couldn't find any other example of the necessary import statement to use the Photos framework APIs.  Thanks!  Stupid apple.  `#import <Photos/Photos.h>` was all I needed

Comment: @sneha anything for delete particular image

Comment: You may need to explicitly link `Photos.framework` in your project